# How to better concurrently process commands in a subversion-like system?

Tags: c#, java, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am developing a SVN-like system (that basically has login/logout + put/get/list/delete commands) that should accept commands from several clients. My idea was to put all the received commands in a (blocking-)queue-like structure, that would execute them sequentially on a different thread.

Later, having more time, I could devise some smart mechanisms to understand if one or more of the next queue messages could be executed concurrently so I could speed up a bit the process (for instance, if both commands I have on the queue are to work on different projects, there are no race condition / shared data issues).

I am now facing the question of deciding if this is really the best solution to the problem. I could just lock files as I'm using them, but I'm afraid that could cause in some particular corner cases a deadlock (although tbh  I still couldn't think of a concrete case where that could happen).

This project is to be used on a network-security class. As such, this SVN thing is just the base on which I'll later lay the core of my security concerns. I wouldn't consider performance to be paramount (but making sure deadlocks don't happen YES!), so the target goal is algorithm correctness.

How would you approach this situation?

Comment: Skipping the usual "do not reinvent the wheel" remark, locking at file level should be more than sufficient for your purpose; it could only deadlock if you don't split locking request to per-file granularity (but why wouldn't you?).

Comment: When I do a PUT "abc.txt" I'm creating a folder named "abc.txt" in the repository, having each version in files 0, 1, 2, 3, ... (that was an imposition, not much I can do about it). So I'm a bit scared that when looking and doing operations over different versions I may have 2 clients wanting to operate on differnt versions at the same time.

Comment: @devouredelysium: I believe that I don't get relly your point on this. Client(s) can "commit" on "server" contemporary more then one version of the same file. But why you worry about concurency in this case if this is "svn like system". Before processing required action over the bulk of the data, check if there is already anewer version of *any* of components in the bulk. Can you please clarify more your scenario?

Comment: @devouredelysium: if you have "abc.txt" with version 2 on the server. Me and you get it from "repository" and work on it, after "contemporary" commit it. There will be only one of us who wins that concurency, so other will be notified, that someone else already updated a version, so please update to the newer one and proceed to your "commit". Like, actually, Subversion does.

Answer (score 1):

I've done several projects of a similar nature. In one iteration we copied the files on the server before streaming them to the client. And for the opposite direction, we streamed to a temp file before overwriting the primary file. It was a mess. Don't do that! The typical internet connection is not much slower than disk these days, and the typical disk transfer is typically slower than the average LAN connection. In addition, are you storing (typically small) source code files in this thing? The file locks will be sufficient to protect the files. Every library these days supports system-level file locking. (Look at the constructor overloads for FileStream in .Net if you don't believe me.) If you need to write data, you attempt to acquire write locks on all the necessary files. If that can't be done you return a timeout error to the user. One system I worked on had permanent, read-only files such that if you wanted people to be able to stream a certain file down all day long you could do so with that flag. If the file locks do prove insufficient, you might look at the .Net [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) class.

I can't see any advantage to manually queuing your put/get/delete requests. That's the server's job, not your job. You don't want to hold all your "put" data in RAM. And you definitely don't want to manage your own upload streams if possible. (We had to write our own native IIS 7 handler for file uploads larger than 2GB. That was a PITA.) Are you familiar with the Concurrency and Instance models in WCF? (If not, you might start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx) I'm most familiar with that, but I assume other server frameworks have similar configuration. I could see some advantage to caching your list data to save you a potential disk hit in that scenario. In one of the projects I worked on we cached NT Domain login tokens. That ended up being a pain and a liability and completely unnecessary. I think the existing frameworks for managing sessions and server-side permissions are sufficient for this.

Comment: "And for the opposite direction, we streamed to a temp file before overwriting the primary file. It was a mess. Don't do that! " I'm actually doing this in the server, as I thought it'd be safer, just in case anything goes wrong while I'm uploading the file. What's the problem with this?

Comment: "I can't see any advantage to manually queuing your put/get/delete requests. " But I am developing both the client and the server!

Comment: I think it's okay to upload to a temp file as long as you can guarantee that the temp file is on the same drive as the final destination. In fact, put it in the same folder as the final destination with a strange extension. (Web browsers do that.) What you don't want to do is let the user configure where temp files go. And if they can configure where the files are stored, don't use %TEMP%. In both of those scenarios you will end up with your temp file going to a different drive. That means a "copy" rather than a "move", which we wanted to avoid.